# JFrame position changes when setting background

Tags: java, swing

I'm learning how to use layouts in JSwing and I'm having a bit of trouble when setting the background image of my JFRame.

I'm using a custom class that overrides paintComponent to use an ImageIcon:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private Image image = null;

    public ImagePanel(String filename) {
        this.image = new ImageIcon(filename).getImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), null);
    }
}
```

This is my main class:

```
public ClientGUI() throws IOException {
        instance = this;

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle("ScanIt");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER)); 

        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel("C:\\barcode_background.jpg");

        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        panel.setLayout(boxLayout);

        panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(30));

        JLabel lblLogo = new JLabel("Scan-It");
        lblLogo.setOpaque(true);
        lblLogo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 48));
        panel.add(lblLogo);

        panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(50));

        JLabel lblEnter = new JLabel("הכנס ברקוד");
        lblEnter.setOpaque(true);
        lblEnter.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 24));
        panel.add(lblEnter);

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(textField);

        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("חפש מוצר");
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new SearchButtonListener());
        panel.add(btnSearch);

        panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(30));

        JButton btnAdmin = new JButton("הוסף מוצר");
        btnAdmin.addActionListener(new AdminButtonListener());
        panel.add(btnAdmin);

        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
```

For some reason, the ImagePanel's size is not the same as the JFrame's size (as shown here: http://prntscr.com/l8d98i). When I set the ImagePanel's size to the JFrame's size, my components all resize. Why's that? As shown here: http://prntscr.com/l8d9ka

```
panel.setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());
```

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason, the ImagePanel's size is not the same as the JFrame's size

Well, you should NOT be setting the size for the frame.

All Swing components are responsible for determining their own size. So you SHOULD be adding all the components to the frame and then you use:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

This will invoke the layout manager and now the size of the frame will be based on the preferred size of the components.

So the problem is with your custom component. You need to implement the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of your image. Then the pack() method of the frame will work properly. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
```

You should NOT manually set the preferred size. As mentioned above, the pack() method will calculate the preferred size.

```
panel.setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());
```

This is not a solution either. The frame contains a title bar and borders, so the size of the panel will NOT be the size of the frame. Again, let the image size determine the preferred size of the frame.

If you need the image to be a specific size, then use the `Image.getScaledInstance(...)` to scale the image.

> When I set the ImagePanel's size to the JFrame's size, my components all resize.

Actually, only the JTextField resizes. For some strange reason the "maximum height" of a JTextField is unlimited. For the JLabel and JButton, the maximum height is the preferred height.

As mentioned by T67 the BoxLayout will resize components up to there maximum size. Although, if you follow my suggestions from above, there will be no need to worry about this. This will only be an issue in future applications when the frame is resizable.

> I'm using a custom class that overrides paintComponent to use an ImageIcon

Why are you creating an ImageIcon, but not using it? Don't use an ImageIcon(...), just to read an image.

Instead use `ImageIO.read(...)` to read the image and get rid of the ImageIcon. This is the proper way to read the image and you will get error message is the image is not found, which helps in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

> When a BoxLayout lays out components from top to bottom, it tries to size each component at the component's preferred height. If the vertical space of the layout does not match the sum of the preferred heights, then BoxLayout tries to resize the components to fill the space. The components either grow or shrink to fill the space, with BoxLayout honoring the minimum and maximum sizes of each of the components. Any extra space appears at the bottom of the container.
>
> Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

You can specify the maximum and minimum dimensions of components using `setMaximumSize()` and `setMinimumSize()`.